# store_product_price doesn't work in certain parts of template

Tags: expresso-store

I have a template where `store_product_price` shows the price (and dynamically updates when modifiers are selected) nearer the top of the template, but moved further down it doesn't.

I need to show the price is a floating sidebar, but placed in that part of the HTML it doesn't work.

I've narrowed it down to the point at which it stops working.

This works (and anywhere higher up in the source):

```
</div>
<p><strong>ITEM TOTAL: <span class="store_product_price"></span></strong></p>
</section>
</div>
```

This doesn't (and anywhere lower down):

```
</div>
</section>
<p><strong>ITEM TOTAL: <span class="store_product_price"></span></strong></p>
</div>
```

Changing `section` to `div` doesn't change anything.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code needs to be within our tag as the JS is added dynamically by the tag. So it will not work outside that area.

Comment: It is. `exp:store:product` is wrapping nearly the whole page.

Comment: Maybe you jQuery is crashing. Not sure, but the injected jquery is not working on your code after that point appears to be the issue.

Comment: I'm including the link to jQuery in the `head` of the page. Not seeing any errors in the console.